# Incremento del almacenamiento del App Service Plan - Azure

Tags: azure

estoy aprendiendo Azure y tengo una duda entorno a los App Service Plans.
Entiendo que un App Service Plan dispone de una cantidad de memoria RAM por cada instancia de máquina virtual.
Sin embargo, en lo referente al espacio de almacenamiento, tengo la duda de si cada vez que creamos una instancia de máquina virtual está consumiendo espacio de disco en el plan.
Por ejemplo, tengo una aplicación que consume 1 GB con una instancia de MV. ¿Si escalamos este plan horizontalmente y creamos 3 instancias de MV ocuparán 3GB de espacio de disco?
Yo entiendo las instancias como copias del contenido del Plan por lo tanto entiendo que por cada instancia se multiplica por dos el consumo de espacio en disco. ¿Es así?

Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas,

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN

Por la descripción que el propio Azure hace de sus planes, concluyo que cada Plan proporciona ACU, memoria RAM y espacio de disco POR CADA INSTANCIA, no para el total del plan.

En el ejemplo de la imagen, cada instancia dispone de 210 de ACU, 3.5GB de memoria y 250GB de almacenamiento

Plan de App Service P1V2:

[image: Plan P1V2]